# Symbol table in the .data section of ELF

Tags: binary, elf, linker

I'm trying to understand how does symbol tables 
relate to the .data section in ELF. First some 
assumptions that I'm using as ground to start with.

> A symbol is a human readable (or "as written in the source file")
>   representation of a function or a variable that is mapped to the
>   actual binary value (that the CPU operates on) of that.

Here is an example

```
//simple.c
int var_global_init = 5;

int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Let's build it and examine the binary:

```
$ gcc simple.c -o simple
$ objdump -t simple | grep var_global_init
  0000000000201010 g     O .data  0000000000000004              var_global_init
```

It lists the symbol in the `.data` section of the ELF file.
Page 20 of the [ELF documentation](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)
defines the `.data` section as:

> These sections hold initialized data that contribute to the program's memory image.

Ok, that kind of fits. So then I ask myself `Does this mean that the symbol table is
embedded in the .data section?`. But that seems to be disproved by the exmple
below:

```
$ readelf -s simple
  Symbol table '.symtab' contains 66 entries:
  ....
  50: 0000000000201010     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 var_global_init
```

`readelf` shows that there is a dedicated `.symtab` section in the ELF that holds
the symbol.

Does the `.data` section need the actual symbol table. The first example
points to concluding that there is one in the `data` section, but shouldn't it be able to execute  just the binary values?

By checking `hexdump` I was able to detect only a single entry, so either I got the concepts wrong or some of them is lying. :)

Comment: Note, though it doesnt help in this case, you may sometimes like to look at the intermediate generated assembler code to see how things work. Compile with `gcc -g -Wa,-alhnd=mylist  simple.c` and you will get in file `mylist` an assembler listing with the original C code mixed in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.data` section contains the data itself, *i.e.* the four bytes which hold the `int` value 5. The `.symtab` section contains the symbols, *i.e.* the names given to various parts of the binary; the `var_global_init` symbol name points to the four bytes of storage in the `.data` section.

That’s why you only see one entry: there is only one symbol, in the symbol table. But you do need both sections if you want to go from a name to a value: the symbol table tells you where to find the value corresponding to the `var_global_init` symbol, and the data section contains the storage for the value.